# Estandarizar o normalizar variables numericas de una base con mezcla de variables numericas y categóricas

Tags: r

Tengo una base de datos donde están mezclado variables numericas y categoricas, quiero aplicar le la fundación scale () a estas variables de forma eficiente es decir, que no tenga que crear otro dataframe con sólo numericas y aplicar la fundación scale() y luego que tener que armar nuevamente la base de datos con cbind()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay varias formas, la más corta y efectiva es con la librería `dplyr`.

## Solución con `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
datos <- data.frame (num1 = rnorm(10, 0, 1), 
                     num2 = rnorm(10, 10, 10), 
                     char1 = letters[1:10])

mutate_if(datos, is.numeric, scale)

num1           num2      char1
1  -0.6713835 -0.2810801     a
2  -1.1075229 -0.5331723     b
3   0.4043045 -0.4210662     c
4  -0.6203845 -1.7037996     d
5  -1.0522031 -0.2737342     e
6   2.0347227  0.9929453     f
7  -0.6050569 -0.6518153     g
8   0.9539465  1.8703961     h
9   0.2077009  0.6891423     i
10  0.4558763  0.3121841     j
```

## Explicación:

1. creo los datos porque la pregunta no contiene un ejemplo.
2. `mutate_if()` aplica condicionalmente una función. En este caso el filtro condicional es `is.numeric`, por lo que aplicará la función solo a las numéricas.
3. Aplica la función `scale`.

Si quisieras agregar algún argumento a `scale` deberías hacerlo después de llamar a la función. Por ejemplo, para no centrar los valores:

```
mutate_if(datos, is.numeric, scale, center = FALSE)
```

## Solución con `base::`

> No hace falta importar librerías.

1. Creamos una función que escala solamente a las variables numéricas. Si no lo son regresa el vector original.

   - Siempre preserva el tipo.
   - No altera el orden de las columnas.
2. Lo aplicamos con `lapply()`
3. Convertimos la lista resultante de `lapply()` a `data.frame`

`escalador_condicional`

Argumentos:

`x` Una lista o data frame con columnas numéricas.

`...` argumentos adicionales para `scale`

```
   escalador_condicional <- function(x, ...) {
   if (is.numeric (x)) { 
   y <- as.vector(scale(x, ...))
   y } else {x}
   }
```

### Test:

```
   data.frame(lapply(datos, escalador_condicional))
```